# knox putFile returns 403

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am getting a 403 error when I attempt to use knox putFile. The odd thing is that it works fine for me when I try it on my local machine, but when it's run from an EC2 instance, I get the 403. Sometimes this also causes an ECONNRESET or EPIPE error, but it's not consistent.

I am running the latest stable versions of node (0.10.5) and knox (0.7.0) both locally and on the EC2 instance.

There are no special characters in the filename other than an underscore, and everything is lowercase. I've gone through the other similar questions here and none of the suggestions helped. I tried updating my server time 'ntpdate -s pool.ntp.org', which had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be caused by an incorrect system time on the EC2 instance. I ran s3cmd and it reported back a RequestTimeTooSkewed error. For some reason the clock was 30 min slow on the EC2 instance, and updating it with 'date -s' fixed the error. Apparently the ntpdate command I had run earlier did not actually do anything.